# How will the Proxima I and II satellites use or test LoRa in space?

Tags: lora, lorawan

IoT Aukland [Tweet](https://twitter.com/IoTakl/status/1061007763763937280) references [FleetSpace](https://twitter.com/fleetspace) and launch of the Proxima I and II satellites.

This put's the "W" in LoRaWan in a different perspective.

How will these test LoRa in space? Is there any chance of linking to Earth (with a non-traditionally large antenna at least)?

Comment: I have a hunch this won't be the last time LoRa is used in space. I wonder if something like an `IoT-in-space` tag could be helpful? See just for example answers to [Have “QR” or other 2D barcodes been used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31915/12102) which mention [Alien Technology RFID Tags](https://blog.atlasrfidstore.com/nasa-rfid-never-lost-space)